# Why is Angular Lazy loading and routing not working after migrating to Angular 6?

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, lazy-loading

In my application , lazy loading was perfectly working in Angular 4 and 5 . However , after I migrated to Angular 6 , the lazy loading and routing has stopped working when I use `ng serve`.

The routes for the application are defined in `app.module.ts` like this :

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'info/:gitCode/:pemCode/:getRtComponent', component: RedComponent },
      { path: 'info/:gitCode/:pemCode/:getFaq/:getRtComponent', component: RedComponent },
      { path: 'loadGuardsInfo/:gitCode/:pemCode/:getRtComponent', component: RedComponent },
      { path: 'loadGuardsInfo/:getRtComponent', component: RedComponent },
      { path: 'recDet', component: RecDetComponent },
      { path: 'SlaveComponent/:pfScreen', loadChildren: './ally/slave/slave.module#SlaveModule' },
      { path: 'MasterComponent/:pfScreen', loadChildren: './ally/master/master.module#MasterModule' },
      { path: 'DashedComponent/:pfScreen', loadChildren: './ally/dashed/dashed.module#DashedModule' }
      ])
  ],
  providers: [ReqService, { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: './' }, {
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
  }, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: []
```

I have gone through a lot of articles on the internet about this and tried out a lot of things , but none worked .
While migrating from angular 5 to 6, a lot of configurations in the old code got changed like : `angular-cli.json` got changed to `angular.json` . Lot of packages in `package.json` got upgraded and 2 new packages got introduced : `@angular-devkit/build-angular`  and `rxjs-compat` . The package : `@angular-devkit/build-angular` seems to be utilized by the `angular.json` for build and serve . I am not understanding why the migration has broken the routing and lazy loading .

Can someone please help me out here ?

Comment: Anybody has ideas or faced a similar situation before ? Any help is greatly appreciated . Nothing's panning out for me at the moment.